# I'm trying to trigger a cURL response to a form in a single script and am running into a roadblock

Tags: php, forms, curl, response

I'm trying to create a script that will run a cURL command when a form is submitted and have yet to successfully receive an email. The Courier API will call an email template I've created through courier.com. Any ideas?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "https://api.courier.com/send",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'header' => 'MY AUTH TOKEN',
        'event' => 'personalized-welcome-email',
        'recipient' => 'RECIPIENT ID',
        'profile' => '{"email":"MY EMAIL ADDRESS"}',
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}

// result sent by the remote server is in $result

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well what's the problem exactly? You stated a requirement but no problem. What happens when you run the code? It's not clear what your "roadblock" is although I note you haven't used the form data to put into the curl request. Is that the issue?

Comment: Hi - the issue is I'm not receiving the email I've tried to plug into the cURL command above

Comment: Ok. Have you checked the result you get back from cURL? do you have documentation of the API endpoint please? We don't know what it will expect, but I would guess the auth token is _probably_ supposed to be in the header rather than the body

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.